# Problem with passing argument string[] args from another class

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code in one class (Code1.cs) and another one in a different class (Code2.cs). I'm trying to use `public static void Main(string[] args]`) in middle of the Code2.cs. In Code2 I'm trying to reach the static void like that: `IssueLayer.Main()` and of course the error appears, the main method asks for the argument `string[] args`.

I have a problem with passing the argument in a right way, I have tried `Issue.Main(args);` but an error appears: The name 'args' does not exist in the current context.

I have tried some other methods which I don't remember right now, please, help me to avoid this error somehow...

Comment: can't you just pass in a blank `args` param?  i.e. call `IssuerLayer.Main(new string[0])`

Comment: Can you please provide some code? That is far easier to understand than your description.

Comment: If `Main` does not use `args` then you can remove it from the declaration, e.g. `public static void Main()`

Comment: @GPW I tried that but the code won't run.  Main does use args

Comment: It is highly unusual to call `Main` from within the program. This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you need to start the program over, chances are you need a `while` loop or some other flow of control that doesn't involve calling `Main`. Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: @JohnWu There's a web-site check job and I'm trying to do the following thing: if an exception occurs in that job, with help of the `Main` I will create an issue in JIRA.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize `main` using an empty string array. For example using 
`Issue.Main(new string[0]);`.

However, this method gets called during startup of your program. I would recommend to write another method with the functionality you want to run, and call that method instead.

Comment: What do you mean in writing "another method"?

Comment: I assume you have written some logic in your main method. You can create some method like `RunMyLogic() {}` and call that from your `Main(args)` method. Then you can also call `Issue.RunMyLogic()` instead of the `Main(args)` method which is cleaner in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can obtain command line arguments with a help of `Environment` class:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

Note, that the first item - `args[0]` is the name of exe, that's why you may want to skip it. And so you can call

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static void Main(string[] args) {
  ...
} 

...

private static void MyOtherMethod() {
  ...
  // Call Main with the same arguments as OS has done it
  Main(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Skip(1).ToArray());
  ...
}
```

But I suggest *extracting a method* from `Main` and call it whenever you want:

```
private static void MyRoutine() {
  //TODO: Extracted business logic here
  ... 
}

...

private static void Main(string[] args) {
  ...
  MyRoutine();
  ...
}

...

private static void MyOtherMethod() {
  ...
  MyRoutine();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well...

As I did a very deep research, somehow it occurred that there was some kind of security issue.

Under `Main(string[] args)` `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;` and `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` were added and from another class now I pass argument like this: `CreateIssue(new sting[0])` and the issue was solved.

Thanks for contributions